# Comparação de datas com classe data personalizada

Tags: c#, datetime

Por motivos de projeto, a classe **DateTime** do .NET não é adequada para mim. Por isso resolvi criar minha própria versão:

```
public class HolidayDateTime
{
    public readonly uint[] RangeValueDay = { 1, 31 };
    public readonly uint[] RangeValueMonth = { 1, 12 };
    public readonly uint[] RangeValueHour = { 0, 23 };
    public readonly uint[] RangeValueMinute = { 0, 60 };

    public uint Day { get; private set; }
    public uint Month { get; private set; }
    public uint Hour { get; private set; }
    public uint Minute { get; private set; }

    protected HolidayDateTime() {   }

    public HolidayDateTime(uint day, uint month, uint hour, uint minute)
    {
        Guard.IntengerRangeInvalid((int)day, (int)RangeValueDay[0], (int)RangeValueDay[1], "O dia informado é inválido");
        Guard.IntengerRangeInvalid((int)month, (int)RangeValueMonth[0], (int)RangeValueMonth[1], "O mês informado é inválido");
        Guard.IntengerRangeInvalid((int)hour, (int)RangeValueHour[0], (int)RangeValueHour[1], "A hora informado é inválida");
        Guard.IntengerRangeInvalid((int)minute, (int)RangeValueMinute[0], (int)RangeValueMinute[1], "O minuto informado é inválido");

        Day = day;
        Month = month;
        Hour = hour;
        Minute = minute;
    }

    public string DateFullToString() => Day + @"/" + Month + " " + Hour + ":" + Minute;

    public uint[] DateFullToArray() => new uint[] { Day, Month, Hour, Minute };
```

No projeto eu precisarei fazer comparações entre as datas, para isso precisarei sobrecarregar os operadores **>**, **<**, **==**, **>=**, **<=** e **!=**

Para os operadores **==** e **!=** a lógica booleana é tranquila de fazer:

```
public static bool operator ==(HolidayDateTime hdaydt1, HolidayDateTime hdaydt2) => hdaydt1.Day == hdaydt2.Day && hdaydt1.Month == hdaydt2.Month && hdaydt1.Hour == hdaydt2.Hour && hdaydt1.Minute == hdaydt2.Minute;

public static bool operator !=(HolidayDateTime hdaydt1, HolidayDateTime hdaydt2) => hdaydt1.Day != hdaydt2.Day || hdaydt1.Month != hdaydt2.Month || hdaydt1.Hour != hdaydt2.Hour || hdaydt1.Minute != hdaydt2.Minute;
```

Minha dificuldade está nos operadores **>**, **<**,**>=** e **<=** pois a combinação booleana para definir se uma data é maior, menor, maior-ou-igual, menor-ou-igual, é enorme o que resultaria em um código difícil de ler e grande.

Gostaria de dicas de uma solução melhor.

Comment: Na verdade eu nem cheguei a tentar, pois mentalmente eu já previa que resultaria em um código monstruoso e bizarro.
Com _string_ até daria certo para os operadores **==** e **!=** mas não vejo possibilidade para os demais operadores.

Comment: Ummmm, converter para numérico, sim, pode ser a solução...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode simplificar as comparações trando a 'data/hora' como strings, desde que obedeça a hierarquia de progressão e um formato fixo.

Para simplificar, eu criei um método que coloca o `HolidayDateTime` no formato de string fixo definido (`MMddHHmm`):

```
private static string GetString(HolidayDateTime hdt)
{
    return hdt.Month.ToString("00") + hdt.Day.ToString("00") + hdt.Hour.ToString("00") + hdt.Minute.ToString("00");
}
```

Uso esse mesmo método na sobrecarga do `ToString` (para fins de apresentação somente):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return GetString(this);
}
```

Na criação dos operadores, uso o método [`string.Compare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zkcaxw5y(v=vs.110).aspx) para determinar se é maior, menor ou igual:

```
public static bool operator >=(HolidayDateTime hdaydt1, HolidayDateTime hdaydt2) => string.Compare(GetString(hdaydt1), GetString(hdaydt2)) >= 0;
public static bool operator <=(HolidayDateTime hdaydt1, HolidayDateTime hdaydt2) => string.Compare(GetString(hdaydt1), GetString(hdaydt2)) <= 0;
public static bool operator >(HolidayDateTime hdaydt1, HolidayDateTime hdaydt2) => string.Compare(GetString(hdaydt1), GetString(hdaydt2)) > 0;
public static bool operator <(HolidayDateTime hdaydt1, HolidayDateTime hdaydt2) => string.Compare(GetString(hdaydt1), GetString(hdaydt2)) < 0;
```

[Veja o exemplo executando no dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/znrL2j)

Espero que isso ajude.

Comment: Fui pesquisar qual o retorno do método _Compare_, a documentação diz que retorna um inteiro que indica sua posição relativa na ordem de classificação.
Não entendi muito bem que retorno é esse.

Comment: Esse método usa um algorítimo de ordenanção. Se o resultado for menor que zero, quer dizer que a primeira string é anterior à segunda, se for igual estaria 'na mesma posição' e se for maior a primeira é posterior à segunda em uma ordenação alfabética ascendente.

Answer (score 4):

Muitas pessoas consideram que a API de data do .NET não é adequada. Para isso foi criada a [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/). Se ela não for adequada, é 99.999999% certo que está fazendo algo errado.

**Essa é a solução melhor**.

Não reinvente a roda. O que o Jon Skeet fez foi reinventar a roda do jeito certo. Reinventar a roda vale quando há profundo entendimento do problema e se sabe que fará algo melhor, o que não é o caso do seu código, tem vários problemas nele, principalmente para alguém que está preocupado com a legibilidade do código. Quase todos os mecanismos da linguagem usados nele são inadequados.

[image: Ferrari futurística com rodas de pedra]

Comment: Olá, sim, minha solução de _DateTime_ é simples e não lá muito bela. Porém em momento algum eu quis criar um "substituto" para a _DateTime_ e disponibilizar na internet para quem quiser usar. É uma solução pobre simples para ser usada apenas na solução que estou trabalhando e apenas em um lugar específico, tanto que em outros lugares estou usando o _DateTime_ padrão .NET.
Minha intenção não é criar algo melhor que o _DateTime_, longe disso, apenas algo que se atenda ao meu caso específico. De qualquer forma vou sim verificar o _NodaTime_.